# How to use list.range function dynamically in power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the table :

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Wn3.png)

I want output of category column like containing rows of H,I,J,K as well when i use split column with delimeters.

How do I do the same dynamically?

How can i use list.range function with text.beforedelimiter and text.afterdelimiter to get rows of H,I,J,K as well in column 'Category'?

Sample output :

```
Category    Month       Cost 
------------    ---------       -------
A           January     2887
A           February    570
.
.
.
H       September   602
H       October     1204
H       November    1011
H       December    2699
I       September   602
I       October     1204
I       November    1011
I       December    2699
J       September   602
J       October     1204
J       November    1011
J       December    2699
K       September   602
K       October     1204
```

Comment: can you post the sample output table?

Comment: @AshokAnumula I have added sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform you category column into individual **Lists**.
Then expand the lists into rows.

For example:

```
 //Transform first column into lists of categories
    xForm1 = Table.TransformColumns(Previous Step, {"Category",
                each if Text.Contains(_,"-") then 
                    {Text.Split(_,"-"){0}..Text.Split(_,"-"){1}} 
                    else Text.Split(_,",")}
```

**Source**
[image]

**Lists**
[image]

**Expanded Lists**
[image]

To get your desired output,

- You will probably want to replace `0` with *`null`*
- Select the first column
- Unpivot other columns

Here is M code to xform your original data into your desired results:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category",Text.Type}} & 
       List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
                each {_,Int64.Type})),
    
    //Transform first column into lists of categories
    xForm1 = Table.TransformColumns(typed, {"Category",
                each if Text.Contains(_,"-") then 
                    {Text.Split(_,"-"){0}..Text.Split(_,"-"){1}} 
                    else Text.Split(_,",")}),
    
    //Replace 0's with nulls so they won't show up in the unpivot
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(xForm1,0,null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        Table.ColumnNames(xForm1)),

    //Expand the List Column into rows
    #"Expanded Category" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Category"),

    //Unpivot the data (month) columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Expanded Category", {"Category"}, "Month", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

**Source**

[image]

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **Custom Column** using this below code in **Power Query Editor** -

```
List.Range({Text.At([Category],0)..Text.At([Category],Text.Length([Category]) - 1)}, 0)
```

You will get an output as below-

[image]

Now you can apply **Expand to new rows** to the new list output and you will get results as below-

[image]

Now you can do your other calculations over the output.